# Integration test with Seam: Actually render a view

Tags: testing, seam

Seam integration tests using TestNG can test components in their container, and even process Faces requests. However, as the Seam manual notes, “This approach tests everything except the view.”

Now we had quite a stupid mistake in one of our XHTML pages (access to a non-existing attribute), and I imagine even a very simple test that just renders the view would have failed. But how to accomplish such a test, when normally the view is not rendered in the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web testing framework. We're using selenium, but there are other alternatives, such as windmill.

Some best practices that we have learned over the years:

- It is generally tricky to test the sort of hybrid pages that Seam generate. Maintaining them are fairly time-consuming, so you need to pick a few important tests to maintain.
- Make sure you build enough infrastructure that developers can easily run these tests on their own workstation.
- Since they are somewhat cumbersome, having a continuous integration server that runs these tests helps.

Comment: I believe Selenium is a very good approach, but isn’t it quite heavy-weight? A continuous integration server is a must for us. X? Firefox? Is installation a major hassle?

Comment: On Linux, you want selenium-grid, Xvfb and firefox. This gives you a headless machine that can run your tests. Is selenium heavyweight? Rather, it is the browser that is heavy-weight. So any testing framework that uses an actual browser will be somewhat heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [JSFUnit](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit) - I've used it reasonably successfully with Seam.